# How can i refresh woocomerce checkout page every 20 seconds?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with a `woocommerce` site I have.

The **problem** is that I need to refresh the checkout page every `20` seconds when I hit the **place order** button.

The main reason is that I have a plugin that informs in real time the user for the order. Also it process the order to be from "**onhold**" to "**completed**" automatically.

But for some reason in `iPad` -`iPhones` it isn't refreshing, so is there any possible solution to refresh the checkout page automatically?

This is the code I use to update the checkout status automatically:

```
/* Reset status of new orders from "on-hold" to "complete" */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
     if ( !$order_id )
        return;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

Thanks all for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

hi put below code into function.php

```
function reload_page( $atts ){
    if(is_checkout()) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 20000);
</script>
<?php }

}
add_shortcode( 'reloadpage', 'reload_page' );
```

and put this shortcode **[reloadpage]** into checkout page. this will reload page after every 20sec.

hope this will work for you

Comment: Hi Corlax, unfortunatelly this isn't work for me because i need to update the page after i press the button "place order" otherwise when the user tries to import the personal data ,can't do it because of the refresh..But really thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work with the help of Corlax..So just for educational purposes...If i want to loop only one time in 20 sec, what else i have to edit in javascript?

Here is the code:

```
/* Reset status of new orders from "on-hold" to "complete" */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
     if ( !$order_id )
        return;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );


{ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 20000);

</script>
<?php }
}
```